# Use of null-coalescing operator and difference b/w ?? and ??= operators

Tags: c#, .net

Already know how to use ?? operator

```
int b = a ?? 0;
```

but the question is when to use ??= in C#

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)? Is there anything unclear with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when to use `??=` operator?

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

> The null-coalescing assignment operator `??=` assigns the value of its right-hand operand to its left-hand operand only if the left-hand operand evaluates to `null`.

For example,

```
int? a = null;
...
a ??= 5;   //Here a is null, so assign 5 to a
int b = a ?? 0;
```

---

```
a ??= 5;
```

can be written like,

```
a = a ?? 5;
```